# How to fill gaps in a sequence of integers, by choosing the best complementary sequence

Tags: algorithm, integer, sequence

Say i have this list of integers :

List A = 3 5 9 10 11 15

Say I have several other lists of integers :

List B1 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 20 25

List B2 = 4 7 8 13 17

List B3 = 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17

NB :

- in A, 4 is a gap (idem for 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14)
- in B1, 1, 2, 20 and 25 are fat : superfluous because inferior to the min in A or superior to the max in A

Is there any algorithm that :

1. tells if a B list fills all the gaps in the A list - or not ;
2. (if some gaps are not filled) tells which B list fills gaps in the A list **the best** = highest number of gaps filled and lowest number of fat

I guess it is a classical need...

ps : i prefer .py code but pseudo-code is ok

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Not yet, because i don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: then do your own research

Comment: What about collisions between the A and B lists?  For example both A and B1 have a `5` - does that count against B1?

Comment: @gcbenison Very good question, thanks. I would say 'no'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two iterators over the sorted arrays of A and B. The first iterates over A and the second over B. Whenever there is a gap in A the next number in B must fill it. Like this (example in C#):

```
var iterA = A.Sort().GetEnumerator();
var iterB = B.Sort().GetEnumerator();

iterA.MoveNext(); iterB.MoveNext();
var prevA = iterA.Current;
var curB = iterB.Current;

if (curB < prevA) return "B is fat";

while (iterA.MoveNext()) {
  var curA = iterA.Current;
  if (curA - prevA == 1) {
    prevA = curA;
    continue; // no gap
  }
  while (curA - prevA > 1) {
    if (curB != prevA + 1) return "B does not fill gap";
    if (iterB.MoveNext()) {
      curB = iterB.Current;
      prevA++;
    } else return "B does not fill gap";
  }
  prevA = curA;
}
```

The runtime complexity would be linear O(N) with N being the numbers between min(A) and max(A). This is just an example to give you an idea on how to approach this problem. I do not guarantee correctness of this algorithm, I have not compiled or tested it. I don't know python, but I assume that it does provide something similar to C#'s iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will do it

```
1) Store the gaps of A, in an array.
2) Then Map each element of A With different B(B1,B2,..)
3) And then display the result, based on the result in the above step
```

This is a brute force approach to solve this problem.